# Vuelidate with Vue 3 & vue-class-component & TypeScript

Tags: vue.js, debugging, vuelidate, vue-class-components

I'm trying out [Vulidate](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/guide.html#basics) with Vue 3, but I can't get it to fit into my typical pattern using the vue-class-component & Typescript syntax.  I see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987113/vuelidate-with-vue-3-vue-class-component-typescript), but I expect there have been some breaking changes that cause the same issues I am having, now.  Can anyone help translate this?

This example works, and it's what I'm trying to learn to convert:

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email..."  v-model="email" @blur="v$.email.$touch" :class="{error: v$.email.$error}" >

        <div v-if="v$.email.$error">
          <p v-if="v$.email.email.$invalid && email !==''"
          >Invalid Email</p>
          <p v-if="v$.email.required.$invalid"
          >Required</p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" style="background-color:yellow"
        >Submit</button>
      </div>
    </template>
```

```ts
    <script lang="ts">
    import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
    import {required, email} from "@vuelidate/validators";
    
    export default {
      setup () {
        return { v$: useVuelidate() }
      },
      data(){ return{ email: null, } },
      validations:{ email:{ required, email } }
    }
    </script>
```

```css
    <style scoped lang="scss"> .error{ color:red; } </style>
```

I've tried a lot of different arrangements, but here's my most recent [broken] script... The immediate problem is, in the template, `v$.email` is not recognized: `Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Ref<Validation<ValidationArgs<unknown>, unknown>>'.ts(2339)` Which makes me think I'm not "registering" email with Vuelidate properly.

```ts
    <script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Options } from "vue-class-component";
    import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
    import {required, email} from "@vuelidate/validators";
    //import { Validate } from "vuelidate-property-decorators"; 
     @Options({
       validations:{
         email:{required,email}
       }
     })
    export default class ValidationsAsClass extends Vue {
      v$ = useVuelidate();
      
      //Use of decorator would be best...
      //@Validate({required,email})
      email = "";
     
    }
    </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Any source to learn more about translating standard Vue to class-component syntax would be greatly appreciated, as well.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you. And if you search for "typescript" in github or vuelidate doc then,,...nothing. It seems vuelidate 2 is still not there, ie working with typescript

Comment: I'm getting a bad feeling my fav extension isn't part of the Vue 3 in-crowd... https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#better-type-inference

Comment: I opened a ticket in github: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/1042